# "Data source name not found" error in release version, not in debug version

Tags: c#, odbc, runtime-error

I have a 32-bit WinForms C# application developed in VS 2015 that connects to Access databases using ODBC. When the application is built in debug mode it works fine, suggesting that the ODBC connection is properly set up and the drivers are accessible. But the release build, when installed on the same computer, issues a [IM002] error - Data source name not found. How can the type of build affect whether the correct ODBC drivers are found?

Comment: Check the times stamp of the exe file in both debug and bin folder.  Make sure bin is later than the debug that is working.  It is possible that you made changes in the code and built the debug and then forgot to go back and rebuild the release version.

Comment: @jdweng, that would be a possible explanation. To check it out, I rebuilt the debug version and then the release version without changing any code. Running of the two versions gave the same results as described above.

Comment: @singleton, this does not apply in my case because I have no directives in the code. One additional piece of information not mentioned in the original post is that both versions are built for Any CPU and the target platform is x86.

Comment: I would backup bin folder and delete which will force the entire code to get rebuild just in case a dependency is wrong.  Then build the release version first and then the debug.  I do not trust the compiler dependencies.

Comment: @jdweng, I followed the sequence of steps you suggest, but the results are the same. The error only appears with the release version. However, I then rebuilt the release version for the x86 platform rather than Any CPU, and that worked. I'm not sure this should be considered a solution as Any CPU did not cause any problems in VS 2008. I just migrated to VS 2015 from VS 2008, and this is the first time I attempted to build a release version with the later version of VS.

Comment: What oledb driver are you using? (see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff965871(v=office.14).aspx).  I'm having similar issues with Jet moving from XP to Win7.  The Win 7 with office 2007 works but the Win 7 with 2010 doesn't work on an Excel VBA macro.  The 2007 uses LONG while 2010 uses LONG PTR and give errors.  Windows has two sets of drivers.  One for System 32 and a second for WOW 64.  The 64 bit drivers are broken.  Make sure you have latest patches from Microsoft.

Comment: @jdweng - This code uses ODBC rather than OLE drivers. The 32-bit ODBC data source looks to the sysWOW64 folder for MS Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb). One would think that the difference in data type would affect debug and release builds similarly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment by @jdweng, it's also worth taking a look to see if there are any directives that might affect the code generated between debug and release versions of the executable. Anything containing blocks such as the one below.

```
#if DEBUG
    // connect to database...
#endif
```